# How to fit table in a page

Tags: tables, margins

I am new to latex, and saw a lot of other questions asking about this, but I could not find a way to fit my 5 column table in a page.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Area of Interest & Pearson Correlation and p-value & Spearman correlation and p-value & Mean squared error (MSE) & $R^2$ Value\\
    \hline
    Buoy 44097 and satellite $H_s$ (0.25 dd) & (0.9872, 0.05$<$)  & (0.9663, 0.05$<$) & 0.1268 & 0.9683\\
    \hline
    Buoy 44097 and satellite $H_s$ (0.25- 0.5 dd) & (0.9795, 0.05$<$)  & (0.9641, 0.05$<$) & 0.1605 & 0.9586\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Correlation, $R^2$ Value, and MSE values between buoy 44097 and Saral/AltiKa Hs measurements.}
\end{table}
```

I got this:
[image]

Comment: It must be at least one  `X` column. Note also than `c` columns cannot have line breaks, so the width depend on the content, i.e., use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXX}` or `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXXXX}`,  or `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXccc}`, etc.  Run `texdoc tabularx`, BTW, run also `texdoc booktabs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix of  mistake of not using X columns in `tabularx` (btw, `\centering` have no sense if width of is `\textwidth`), and an alternative format using `tabulary` and `booktabs`, also with some others design changes:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,tabulary}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{7em}|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
    Area of Interest & Pearson Correlation and p-value & Spearman correlation and p-value & Mean squared error (MSE) & $R^2$ Value\\
    \hline
    Buoy 44097 and satellite $H_s$ (0.25 dd) & (0.9872, 0.05$<$)  & (0.9663, 0.05$<$) & 0.1268 & 0.9683\\
    \hline
    Buoy 44097 and satellite $H_s$ (0.25- 0.5 dd) & (0.9795, 0.05$<$)  & (0.9641, 0.05$<$) & 0.1605 & 0.9586\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Correlation, $R^2$ Value, and MSE values between buoy 44097 and Saral/AltiKa Hs measurements.}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\tymin0pt\tymax145pt\sffamily\small
\caption{Correlations, $R^2$ Value, and Mean Square Error (MSE) values 
between buoy 44097 and Saral/AltiKa Hs measurements.}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LCCCC}\toprule 
Area of Interest & \mbox{Pearson's $r$} (p-value) & \mbox{Spearman's $\rho$} (p-value) & MSE & $R^2$ \\\midrule
Buoy 44097 and satellite $H_s$ (0.25 dd) & 0.9872 ($<$0.05)  & 0.9663 ($<$0.05) & 0.1268 & 0.9683\\\addlinespace
Buoy 44097 and satellite $H_s$ (0.25--0.5 dd) & 0.9795 ($<$0.05) & 0.9641 ($<$0.05) & 0.1605 & 0.9586\\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```